# Extract Editable div in php

Tags: php, html

It is possible to extract the content of **Editable div** in **php**?? 
If yes, please let me know how I can do it.

(Just let me know that one line code.)

Comment: An editable div is send to the browser and edited in the browser. You would have to use Javascript (AJAX) to sent the edits back to the server where they can be received by a PHP script.